# Bind Date property of Bean to JSP page in Spring MVC3 using <form:form> tag?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Suppose i have bean

```
Class beanA{
//Other properties
private java.util.Date dateOfReciept;

//Getter and Setter methods
}
```

How can i bind 'dateOfReciept' property to jsp page using   tag ?  Is it possible? If yes How ? If not why ?

Comment: Have you tried binding it?

Comment: Yes but i am unsuccessful to

Comment: Include the code which didn't work for you and read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The same which i posted above. I know the guidelines of SO

Comment: Strange thing is i dont get any exception

Comment: You also need to include your JSP form so anybody can see how you tried to bind the bean value and if it might contain an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind `dateOfReciept` as below:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${beanA.dateOfReciept}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" var="dateOfRecieptVar" />
<form:input path="dateOfReciept" value="${dateOfRecieptVar}" />
```

There is no `<form:date>` available: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="modalName">
     Birthday (mm/dd/yyyy):
     <form:input path="dateOfReciept" />
</form:form>
```

will bind input value `09/24/2013` to variable.